# Calling a WCF Service with jquery ajax from Sharepoint Online

Tags: wcf, jquery-ajax

I'm using Sharepoint 365. I would like to call a WCF Service located in a server in my intranet to read data using a script editor webpart and jquery ajax. Anyone has any example of how to accomplish this? I have read that using jsonp and cross-domains but hadn't found any good example. Thanks in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I used these block code to call an application installed in the client and configured to listen a port on the localhost, from a page with a form published in Sharepoint Online. 
In this case I had to asign "http://localhost:xxxx" to call_UrlEndpoint, but try to put your intranet url instead.

```
function openLocalApp(call_UrlEndpoint, dataJson){
$.ajax({
    url: call_UrlEndpoint,
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(dataJson),
    jsonp:"callback",
    jsonpCallback: "save",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    succes: function (response) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("Scanning component failed!");
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Hi Ernesto. I added more detail on the following url: [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/265351/call-on-premises-wcf-service-using-script-editor-webpart-on-sharepoint-online) I just want to be able to call an on premises WCF web service from sharepoint online. If you have any example will be really appreciated. Regards!

Comment: Maybe this can be useful... https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52187.sharepoint-online-cross-origin-resource-sharing-between-js-code-and-remote-web-api.aspx